# Text scrolling vertically up / down animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to create the attached animation using html and css, steps to re-produce are when I hover the text it appears a new text comes from the top, when I stop the hover it seems the same old text comes from the bottom.

My efforts are in the attached JS Bin Link, I am able to achieve the 1st part where it appears the text comes from the top but the second part when the user stops the hover is something I am still struggling with It would be awesome if someone can help me here thanks!.

https://jsbin.com/kuqoroqire/1/edit?html,css,output

```
// Please follow JS Bin for code.
```

[image]

Comment: why not use a SO snippet here? I can't access your jsBin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the same text, `text-shadow` can do this. I wrote a detailed article about this technique: https://css-tricks.com/cool-hover-effects-that-use-css-text-shadow/

```css
.hover {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  color: #0000;
  text-shadow: 
    0 0 #000, 
    0 -1.2em #1095c1;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .3s;
}
.hover:hover {
  text-shadow: 
    0 1.2em #000, 
    0 0 #1095c1;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
h3 {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin:0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 .1em;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="hover">Hover Me</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking in another direction thanks!